# Using STR_to_DATE in PHP SQL Query

Tags: php, sql, mysql, string-to-datetime

I need a way of changing the format the date format from datetime to just the date in an SQL query, I have tried:

```
$sql="SELECT created_by FROM meetings WHERE STR_TO_DATE('date_start', 'Y-m-d')='$CorrectDate'";
```

but to no avail.

date_start is the field in the SQL table.

Any help welcome!!!

Comment: You don't say what your DBMS is: MySQL? Oracle? SQL Server?

Comment: @Alvaro: `STR_TO_DATE` is only available in `MySQL`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  created_by
FROM    meetings
WHERE   date_start >= $correctDate
        AND date_start < $correctDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Unlike any solution which involves a function or an expression over `date_start`, this one is *sargable*, i. e. able to use an index on `date_start` efficiently.

Comment: if the format in SQL is Datetime, would this not still return the time also

Comment: @Bift: return where? Is `created_by` a date column also?